# Display image alt text within a div on page

Tags: jquery, css, image, alt

I have an image displaying as a background on my page through a plugin, and I'm trying to display the ALT text from that image within a DIV elsewhere on the page.

Here's the code that's coming up:

```
<!-- Background Manager Start -->
<div id="myatu_bgm_img_group" class="myatu_bgm_fs" style="overflow: hidden;"><script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
        try{(function(a){myatu_bgm.addTopImage("",function(){if((typeof myatu_bgm!=="undefined")&&(myatu_bgm.initial_ease_in==="true")){a(this).fadeIn("slow")}else{a(this).show()}})}(jQuery))}catch(e){};
    /*]]>*/
    </script><noscript><img id="myatu_bgm_top" class="myatu_bgm_fs" src="http://mgrezova.webfactional.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/agnesbshirt.jpg" alt="Caption Text"   /></noscript></div>
<!-- Background Manager End -->
```

Can someone suggest javascript, or something else, that would allow me to output that "Caption Text" within the following DIV?

```
<DIV class="quote">
    <DIV class="inner-quote">
    </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Any help is hugely appreciated.

Comment: Your image is in a `<noscript>`. Therefore it will only be visible if javascript is not available, so it would not be possible to use any JS to set the text of the `.inner-quote` div. You seem to have made yourself a little paradox :)

Comment: I wondered about that. Perhaps I'm going to have to dig through the plugin code and make it output the ALT in the div. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.inner-quote').html($('#myatu_bgm_top').prop('alt'));
```

Comment: Will the image in the `<noscript>` tag be in the DOM?

Comment: I'm a complete novice with this, but I can't seem to make it work. Could other scripting on the page keep it from loading? Here's the link: http://bit.ly/1awan6Q

Comment: Thanks for the options at least. I do appreciate it. Seems like I'll have to solve it another way.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(".inner-quote").html($("#myatu_bgm_top").attr("alt"));
```